# Spring Resource Transaction Management

Tags: java, spring

When using Spring transactions who's responsible for managing the resource transaction?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that "resource transaction" means in the context of an XA distributed transaction. Then spring will delegate to JTA & JTS in the app server to start,commit,rollback transactions with the resource managers.